# Binding enabled/disabled property to visibility of grid

Tags: wpf

I have a grid which contains some controls, i wish to bind Isenabled property of controls to visibility property of grid. So, if the grid is hidden/collapsed i wish to disable all controls (or at least textboxes) and enable them if grid is visible.

```
<Grid x:Name="fItem" Visibility="hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="10,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="669">
                    <TextBox x:Name="fJm" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="35,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label_Copy" Content="J.m." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Roba" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="94,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="fNaziv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="178,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="302"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Pg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="485,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="fPg" Height="23" Margin="503,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label1_Copy" Content="Cijena:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="530,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="fCijena" Height="23" Margin="570,8,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="78"/>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: To the user it won't make any difference if the controls are enabled or disabled when the grid is hidden. He/she won't be able to change anything, since they are not visible. Why would you want to disable them?

Comment: Because i have an array of all textboxes and if they are enabled/disabled i do different things to content/tab indexes/ tags/reports/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following property to your control which you want to enable disable.

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=fItem, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityToBoolConverter}}"
```

And also add a new converter file here is code of converter

```
 public class VisibilityToBoolConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var visibility = (Visibility) value;
        if (visibility == Visibility.Collapsed || visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your xaml file add following line as well.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:VisibilityToBoolConverter x:Key="visibilityToBoolConverter" ></local:VisibilityToBoolConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

It should work. If you have any other question let me know in comment.

By the way one problem with your code is when gird is hidden/collapsed you won't be able to see the controls are they are child of grid on which you are sitting visibility.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what i needed!